# Version VS realization (of a stochastic process)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, almost-everywhere

I quote *Kuo (2006)*.

> **Definition** A stochastic process $\tilde{X}(t)$ is called a *version* of $X(t)$ if $\mathbb{P}\{\tilde{X}(t)=X(t)\}=1$ for each $t$.

> **Definition** A stochastic process $\tilde{X}(t)$ is called a *realization* of $X(t)$ if there exists $\Omega_0$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\Omega_0)=1$ and for each $\omega\in\Omega_0, \tilde{X}(t,\omega)=X(t,\omega)$ for all $t$.

Then, I read that:

> Obviously, a realization is also a version, but not vice versa.

and that is pretty clear to me. 
 What I cannot understand is the following statement:

> But if the time parameter set is countable, then these two concepts are equivalent.

---

Why is the immediately above statament true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because a countable union of null sets is a null set, i.e., if the (time) parameter set $T$ is countable, then
$$
\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcup_{t\in T}\{\tilde{X}_t\ne X_t\}\right)\le \sum_{t\in T}\mathsf{P}\!\left(\tilde{X}_t\ne X_t\right)=0.
$$

Comment: So, if I am not mistaken, I could rewrite your passage as:
$$\mathsf{P}\bigg(\Omega_0^C\bigg)=0$$
where 
$$\Omega_0^c=\{\omega: \tilde{X}_t(\omega)\ne X_t(\omega)\}$$ Hence
$$\mathsf{P}\bigg(\Omega_0\bigg)=1$$
However, **I cannot understand why a finite union of null sets is not a null set**. Could you please help me understand such a fact? *[continue]* @d.k.o.

Comment: *[continue]* That is, couldn't I state, for $T$ finite set such that $T=\{t_0,\ldots,t_n\}$ that:
$$\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcup_{i=t_0}^{t_n}\{\tilde{X}_i\ne X_i\}\right)\le \sum_{i=t_0}^{t_n}\mathsf{P}\!\left(\tilde{X}_i\ne X_i\right)=0.$$? @d.k.o.

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? A finite union of null sets is obviously a null set.

Comment: Of course. So, why with $$\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcup_{i=t_0}^{t_n}\{\tilde{X}_i\ne X_i\}\right)\le \sum_{i=t_0}^{t_n}\mathsf{P}\!\left(\tilde{X}_i\ne X_i\right)=0.$$ am I not allowed to say that a version is also a realization for finite set $T$? **(as written in the question, on my reference I read instead that for finite set $T$ a version is not necessarily a realization)** @d.k.o.

Comment: You're surely allowed to say that when $T$ is a finite set.

Comment: So, why on my reference I read "Obviously, a realization is also a version, **but not vice versa. But if the time parameter set is countable, then these two concepts are equivalent.**" (meaning that if time set $T$ is finite a version is not necessarily a realization)? That's the question @d.k.o.

Comment: A countable set is either a finite set or a countably infinite set.

Comment: Sorry, probably I am not getting to the point in a clear way. That a realization is also a version (in any case, both for $T$ finite set and for $T$ countable set is clear, as you have just shown in a perfect way). The fact I cannot understand is why on my reference it is said that $$\text{for finite set } T\text{, a version is not necessarily a realization}$$Why that? @d.k.o.

Comment: Where exactly is that quote (in Kuo's book)?

Comment: Sorry, my very silly mistake (I did not have definition of a countable set clear in mind). What it should be meant there is that $$\text{for uncountable set } T\text{, a version is not necessarily a realization}$$Original statement is "Obviously, a realization is also a version, but not vice versa. But if the time parameter set is countable, then these two concepts are equivalent" (ch. 3, p. 30). *[continue]*

Comment: *[continue]* So, at this point, if I am not mistaken, for uncountable set $T$ a version is not necessarily a realization since I cannot state that $$\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcup_{t\in T}\{\tilde{X}_t\ne X_t\}\right)\le \sum_{t\in T}\mathsf{P}\!\left(\tilde{X}_t\ne X_t\right)=0\tag{1}$$Finally, why cannot I state so (that is, $(1)$)? Thank you a lot for your patience and time. @d.k.o.

Comment: Probably it is easier to look at a counterexample. Look at the example in [this quesiton](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150297/difference-between-modification-and-indistinguishable)

Comment: Thank you a lot! I have also found such a question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910175/why-is-an-uncountable-union-of-null-sets-not-necessarily-a-null-set. Accepted answer clears out any doubt @d.k.o.