# A countable union of null sets is again a null set in any measure space

Tags: measure-theory

> Show that in a measure space $(\Omega,\mathscr{A}, \mu)$ where $\mathscr{A}$ is a $\sigma$-field,
> a countable union of null sets is again a null set.

I believe there must be some logical reasoning I'm missing for the following proof otherwise, it would make perfect sense to do the same for an uncountable union of null sets; probably in the last equality. It probably seems silly, but please explain?
$$0\le\mu(\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i)\le\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(A_i)=0$$
where, $A_i$ are null sets from $\mathscr{A}$. I got a [counter-example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2910175/562589), but why does the above proof only work for countable union?

Comment: In the middle $\le$ relation, you used subadditivity, which is only assumed for countable unions.

Comment: @GEdgar Oh RIGHT!